# wxwidgets: SplashScreen with video

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

I am just starting out with wxWidgets and using it to build a GUI around some command line software I wrote.

One thing I wanted to do was have a splash screen for my application and I notice that wxWidgets has a class for that (http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_splash_screen.html). However, this works in a traditional way and takes an image to be displayed as the splash screen. What I would like to do is display a video.

Would it be simple to extend this to play a video instead of displaying an image or is there perhaps another more convenient way to do this with wxWidgets?

Comment: Have a look into the `wxMediaCtrl` class - there's a bunch of examples showing its use with video.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! Just came across it!

Comment: Why? Seriously why? The only sane reason for a splash screen to exist at all is, if your program takes significant time to initialize before it can be used. If your main UI is ready to use in less than 200ms after process start a splash screen is just annoying and have the user's pitchforks swinging. A splash screen should always be the last resort if immediate interactivity can not be obtained.

Comment: @datenwolf I feel your sentiment and I agree but cannot argue with the client on this. Plus, I would rather fight some other battle with them ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`wxSplashScreen` class on its own won't allow you to do it, but you could write your own version based on [its code](https://github.com/wxWidgets/wxWidgets/blob/WX_3_0_2/src/generic/splash.cpp) using `wxMediaCtrl` as mentioned in the comments or maybe just with an animated GIF if this can be enough for your needs.

Answer (score 0):

video system depends on the player, I recommend using gif
look my snippets and load gif from resource file:

extra.h: https://bitbucket.org/snippets/jamilservicos/xK7ga

resources: https://bitbucket.org/snippets/jamilservicos/ey7XK

instructions are in Portuguese, but I think it has you not problem in translation.

remember of the stop () before closing the splash screen